# Excel form lost path

Tags: excel, path

In my file server, some excel files lost their path,

Example:

```
=if(A2='\\172.168.1.1\SHARING\LANAIM\Gest_Qual\05__REG\04__Gest\[file1.xlsx]data'!$A2;2;False)
```

what happens and stay that way:

```
=if(A2='\\172.168.1.1\04__Gest\[file1.xlsx]data'!$A2;2;False)
```

How can I solve this problem? if someone can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden (or not) worksheet with the names of the files that it is to link to.  Then use a VLOOKUP to handle the names.  That way you can changes the file names in the lookup table and the links will redirect as needed.

Someone may have answered "yes" to update the links as some point and that caused them to change.

----EDIT----

I just thought of something:

1. Rename \172.168.1.1\SHARING\LANAIM\Gest_Qual\05_*REG\04*_Gest\ **file1.xlsx**
   to **file2.xlsx**
2. Open \172.168.1.1\04__Gest\ **file1.xlsx** (Create it there if it does
   not exist)
3. Open the file that has the links in it.
4. Verify that changes to **file1.xslx** appear in the linked file
5. You should now have 2 files open (the linked file and the dummy **file1.xslx**).
6. Use "Save As" to save **file1.xlsx** to the location that you want the links to point to (\172.168.1.1\SHARING\LANAIM\Gest_Qual\05_*REG\04*_Gest\ **file1.xlsx**).
7. Close **file1.xlsx** then close the linked file.
8. Rename \172.168.1.1\SHARING\LANAIM\Gest_Qual\05_*REG\04*_Gest\ **file2.xlsx**
   back to original **file1.xlsl** (deleting the dummy **file1.xslx** in the process).
9. Open your linked file and the links should now point to the correct
   **file1.xslx**.